# Turn shape into individual paths - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

Is it possible in Illustrator to automatically cut a shape of points so each segmented line is separated?

[image: Standard star]

[image: A segmented line from a star]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the Direct Select Tool (A).
2. Select all of the points.
3. Hold Shift and select 1 of the anchor points to deselect one of the anchor points
4. Select `Cut path of selected anchor points` in the Anchor Point toolbar (The icon with the segmented line and scissors).

[image: Anchor options]

5. Now go back to the last anchor point and select it with the Direct Select Tool (A) and click on the `Cut path of selected anchor points` button to cut the last anchor point.